# How to match a recurring group

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I search quite a bit on google for this answer. Perhaps it is easy but in my case I did not manage to find the solution.

How to match and parse it in groups with regex
`service-page-name/32/54/regular/superize`

I am trying to use preg_match and I would like to have

**groupe 1 -> service-page-name**

**groupe 2 -> /32**

**groupe 3 -> /54**

**groupe 4 -> /regular**

**groupe 5 -> /supersize**

Important obviously there is the possibility to add n numbers of parameters not just the 4 we have here in addition of the page.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you want to use `preg_split('~(?=/)~', $s)`? Or `explode('/', $s)`? You won't be able to use `preg_match` here since the number of groups is always constant and you mention *Important obviously there is the possibility to add n numbers of parameters*.

Comment: Please tag your programming language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's solution:

```
preg_match_all("/(\/?[\w-]+)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

you can check results of this pattern & tweak it in realtime here: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/oD5

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had to use `preg_match_all` instead!